# CarrierWave remote_image_url not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a Rails 4 app and I'm using CarrierWave to grab an image from a url. In my form_for the url is passed into params just fine, but I can't seem to get the url to save. When I take a look at the last `Stamp` saved, `remote_image_url` is `nil`. I'm sure it's something simple, but the documentation is pretty woeful.

And just to confirm; CarrierWave works perfectly when uploading an image from file using the `f.file_field` in the form.

Here is my code:

`stamp_uploader.rb`:

```
class Stamp < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, StampUploader
  mount_uploader :remote_image_url, StampUploader
end
```

`stamps_controller`:

```
def show
    @stamp = Stamp.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @stamp = Stamp.new
end

def create
    @stamp = Stamp.create(stamp_params)

    if @stamp.save
        flash[:success] = "Thanks for your submission!"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def stamp_params
    params.require(:stamp).permit(:image, :remote_image_url)
end
```

`new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @stamp do |f| %>
  <%= image_tag(current_user.image) %>
  <%= f.label :remote_image_url, "Upload Image" %>
  <%= f.text_field :remote_image_url, value: current_user.image %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

`schema.rb`:

```
create_table "stamps", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "image"
  t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
  t.string   "remote_avatar_url"
  t.string   "remote_image_url"
end
```

params:

```
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"rA8KaI+bG5ygldeQC2n00z3BuEfiA0xO4tukUUL3tvG19G7WQCuMMqwzwWzWSMbKlT+2W5KsJYF4Q/lXg9OHeA==",
 "stamp"=>{"remote_image_url"=>"https://graph.facebook.com/10157057736060574/picture?width=1000&height=1000"},
 "commit"=>"Create Stamp",
 "controller"=>"stamps",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

Comment: Can you post the params your controller receives (from your rails console)?

Comment: Sure, added to the main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your line `mount_uploader :remote_image_url, StampUploader` is what messes it up. Try removing it and see if things work.

When you do `mount_uploader :foo, StampUploader`, I believe CarrierWave defines (among other things) `foo=` and `remote_foo_url=` methods for you.

So when you later do `mount_uploader :remote_image_url, StampUploader`, you're overwriting the `remote_image_url=` method you just got with another method that despite its name expects a file, not a URL.

If this helps, may I suggest that you pay it forward by making a pull request to CarrierWave to clarify the docs, if you found them unclear? :)

Comment: Yep, works perfectly now! I removed that `mount_uploader` and I also removed the corresponding column from the database as `:remote_image_url` uses the `:image` column.